# In RTL drirection, page scrolls up only once when page load by clicking any button or toggling any class, why?

Tags: jquery

When a page loads & its direction is 'rtl', then for the first time if user click any button it takes user to top of the page, why it is happening can not b able to find the reason??

Comment: Can you elaborate with more details like code that you have tried, case when that is happening and when not, and why you think this is related to jquery so that its easier to help?